# Reducing Runtime of BERT Embedding Extraction in PyTorch

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, bert-language-model

I'm using BERT from Hugging Face's Transformers library in PyTorch to extract embeddings for text data, aiming to integrate these embeddings into a machine learning pipeline. Despite the success in capturing rich textual features, the extraction process significantly slows down my pipeline, especially when processing large datasets. I'm looking for targeted advice to optimize this specific phase of my workflow.

Below is the minimal code snippet representing my current approach:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', return_dict=False)

def extract_embeddings(text):
    inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, max_length=512)
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    embeddings = outputs[0][:,0,:].detach()
    return embeddings

# Example usage
text = "Here is some example text to encode"
embeddings = extract_embeddings(text)
```

Given this context, my question is specific:

1. **How can I optimize the runtime of the BERT embedding extraction process in PyTorch for large datasets?**

I'm particularly interested in any PyTorch-specific techniques or practices that can help speed up this operation, such as adjustments to batch size, use of PyTorch DataLoader for efficient batching, or model inference optimizations that do not compromise the quality of the embeddings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tricks to speed up the process.

### Caching

If the dataset is not changing very often, we can focus on new sentence only and store a map from sentences to tensors.

### DataLoading

Properly identify operations that do not require the model, and put them in the DataLoader. I find the [pytorch DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) effective to dispatch data loading operation on multiple workers, speeding up the training / inference loop.

Another solution is to prepare batch in advance, compute tokenization for these batches and store tokenized batch somewhere.

Paired with parallelization techniques, it avoid using workers to load data, worker would only process data into the model.

### Compilation

Use `model.compile` (available in torch^2.0) to speed up the model.

### Parallelization

If you own multiple GPU or even a single GPU, you can try to parallelize inference. You can look the processing usage of the GPU and see if you extract more juice from it. You can do as follow to parallelize on a single machine (it saves 10s on my machine on 5000 sentences, originally took 55s for the same process):

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from tqdm import tqdm
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time


def load_model(model_package: str, device: str):
    return (
        AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_package),
        AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_package, return_dict=False).to(device),
    )


def embed_sentences(model, tokenizer, sentences: list[str], device="cpu"):
    inputs = tokenizer(
        sentences, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=512
    ).to(device)
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    return outputs[1].detach().cpu().numpy()


def worker_main(
    model_package: str, device: str, input_queue: mp.Queue, output_queue: mp.Queue
):
    tokenizer, model = load_model(model_package, device)
    while True:
        batch = input_queue.get()
        if batch is None:
            return
        outputs = embed_sentences(model, tokenizer, batch, device)
        output_queue.put((batch, outputs))


def storage_main(output_queue: mp.Queue, output_fp: str, total: int):
    tic = None
    pbar = tqdm(range(total))
    with open(output_fp, "wb") as stream:
        while True:
            output = output_queue.get()
            if tic is None:
                tic = time.time()

            if output is None:
                tac = time.time()
                print(f"elapsed time {tac - tic}")
                break

            sentences, vectors = output
            for sentence, vector in zip(sentences, vectors):
                np.save(stream, sentence)
                np.save(stream, vector)
                pbar.update(1)


def dispatch_sentences_on_workers(
    all_sentences: list[str],
    model_package: str,
    num_workers: int,
    device: str,
    batch_size: int,
    output_fp: str,
):
    input_queue = mp.Queue()
    output_queue = mp.Queue()

    # start processes
    worker_processes = [
        mp.Process(
            target=worker_main, args=(model_package, device, input_queue, output_queue)
        )
        for _ in range(num_workers)
    ]
    storage_process = mp.Process(
        target=storage_main, args=(output_queue, output_fp, len(all_sentences))
    )
    for p in worker_processes:
        p.start()
    storage_process.start()

    # put process data
    for i in range(0, len(all_sentences), batch_size):
        input_queue.put(all_sentences[i : i + batch_size])

    # stop worker processes
    for _ in worker_processes:
        input_queue.put(None)
    for p in worker_processes:
        p.join()

    # stop storage process
    output_queue.put(None)
    storage_process.join()


dispatch_sentences_on_workers(
    [your_sentences...],
    "bert-base-uncased",
    2,
    "cuda:0",
    1,
    "test.npy",
)
```

Some other things to investigate:

- Kubeflow
- Quantization, it will reduce model size, and may allow you to process bigger batches or parallelize more.